Docker containers and environment variables
I've always found it hard to get my head around environment variables, where there set and where certain commands are run.
I have a Dockerfile which extends from another
Base Dockerfile:
COPY process_config.sh /bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/process_config.sh"]

Service Dockerfile:
From base:latest

..some config

CMD ["python3" "/code/flights.py"]

In process_config.sh
I would like to edit the environment variables, so that the docker container uses the updated environment variable.
I run
export $env_name=updated_config

...

exec "$@"

in the process_config.sh but the environment variable doesn't get updated and within the docker container it's the old value.
What am I missing?

That should work fine; in your Python script if you look at os.environ['env_name'] you should see its value.  docker run --rm your-image env should also show it.  docker exec does not run via the entrypoint wrapper, though, and won't see the environment variable.

@DavidMaze thank you - I was being an idiot running docker exec to verify

another thing to note is the difference is how env vars are handled by non-interactive shells
